# white background for cutFromCenter function

Tags: php, image

I am following [this code](https://gist.github.com/miguelxt/908143) to crop and resize images in php. However, when I use **cutFromCenter** function, it is automatically filling the image with black colour, I want to fill it with white.

```
public function cutFromCenter($width, $height) {

    if ($width < $this->getWidth() && $width > $height) {
        $this->resizeToWidth($width);
    }
    if ($height < $this->getHeight() && $width < $height) {
        $this->resizeToHeight($height);
    }

    $x = ($this->getWidth() / 2) - ($width / 2);
    $y = ($this->getHeight() / 2) - ($height / 2);

    return $this->cut($x, $y, $width, $height);
}
```

usage:

```
$resizeimage->load('img/ori.jpg');
$resizeimage->cutFromCenter(320,250);
$resizeimage->save('img/new.jpg');
```

any way to make the function to fill the small images with white colour?

this is the output:

[image: example]

Comment: What image lib are you using for this GD or ImageMagick?

Comment: @MartinBarker I am using this one: https://gist.github.com/miguelxt/908143

Comment: @Elyor Have you tried any of our answers? Some back and forth would be useful

Comment: @Elyor i would say stop trying to mess with a library that you don't understand... the fact i asked you if it's using GD or ImageMagick and you pointed me to the library that your using shows you don't understand whats the library is doing doing messing with code you don't understand is bad. it is using PHP's GD image system as PHP has 2 image systems built into it. so go learn how to use GD on it's own for a while till you get the hang of how it works what is does and then you should be able to understand the library to alter it.

Comment: @Elyor it would also be worth noting once you have an understanding of GD you will probably understand the answer given and be able to implement them or give feed back if they don't work.

Comment: all the 3 answer are the same, but none is working. logically if I change value of `imagecolorallocate` it supposed to change the colour, but when i test, it is still returning black colour.

Comment: @Elyor i have added an answer showing you what you need to change or you can just use my forked version. but it only taken me 20 mins to do that coz i know GD lib and how to use it. it taken me longer to setup my local dev IIS to support PHP :)

Comment: @Elyor, note that in my answer I mentioned that you need to change ALL the usages of `imagecolorallocate`. Did you change all of them or only some of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after about 20 mins fiddling i found your problem and fixed it i have also forked the file so you can download my version from GitHub link is below.

https://gist.github.com/barkermn01/a0ff9dd928ea78443259f8c055f608ac

## What i have done to this.

```
public function cut($x, $y, $width, $height, $bgColor = null) {
    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); 
    imagecolortransparent($new_image, imagecolorallocate($new_image, 0, 0, 0));
    imagealphablending($new_image, false);
    imagesavealpha($new_image, false);
            
    if($bgColor != null){
        $rgb = explode(',', $bgColor);
        $color = imagecolorallocate($new_image, $rgb[0], $rgb[1], $rgb[2]);
        imagefill($new_image, 0, 0, $color);
    }
    ob_start (); 
    imagepng($this->image);
    $imageStr = ob_get_clean(); 
    $src_size = getimagesizefromstring($imageStr);
    imagecopyresampled (
        $new_image, 
        $this->image, 
        ($width-$src_size[0])/2,
        ($height-$src_size[1])/2,
        0, 
        0, 
        $src_size[0], 
        $src_size[1],
        $src_size[0], 
        $src_size[1]);
    $this->image = $new_image;
}
```

**Explanation:**
So change the cut method to use image re-sample copy.
Got the information of the source image though creating the image and then saving it into an buffer and using that buffer to get the size.
added support for an RGB colour sting to be passed in case any one want the background a different colour.

```
public function cutFromCenter($width, $height, $bgColor = null) {
            
    if ($width < $this->getWidth() && $width > $height) {
        $this->resizeToWidth($width);
    }
    if ($height < $this->getHeight() && $width < $height) {
        $this->resizeToHeight($height);
    }
    
    $x = ($this->getWidth() / 2) - ($width / 2);
    $y = ($this->getHeight() / 2) - ($height / 2);
    
    return $this->cut($x, $y, $width, $height, $bgColor);
}
```

**Explanation**
Added support for the background colour RGB String to be passed though null it will default to GD's default.

## Usage changed to:

```
$resizeimage->cutFromCenter(320,250, "255,255,255");
```

Allow an RGB colour string to be passed. in this case white.

## Examples:

[image: Original Image]
[image: Resamapled image cut from centre]

Comment: your solution is working on localhost, but it is not working online. what can be the reason?

Comment: `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function getimagesizefromstring() in`

Comment: Do you have the latest PHP-GD installed?

Answer (score 1):

It could be worth trying to fill the image created with `imagecreatetruecolor` with white before the original image is resized.

```
public function cut($x, $y, $width, $height) {
    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); 

    imagecolortransparent($new_image, imagecolorallocate($new_image, 0, 0, 0));
    imagealphablending($new_image, false);
    imagesavealpha($new_image, true);

    $image = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);

    $white = imagecolorallocate($new_image, 255, 255, 255);
    imagefill($new_image, 0, 0, $white);

    imagecopy($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, $x, $y, $width, $height);

    $this->image = $new_image;
}
```

Have a look if this makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the image is originally created with transparent fill. You need to modify [line 137](https://gist.github.com/miguelxt/908143#file-simpleimage-php-L137) in the cut method to set original image background as white. i.e.

```
imagecolortransparent($new_image, imagecolorallocate($new_image, 255, 255,255));
```

Comment: Basically, you should check the other functions it passes through. A second look shows me there's a resize method which also passes a `0, 0, 0` in `imagecolorallocate`.

Comment: `imagecolortransparent($new_image, imagecolorallocate($new_image, 0, 0, 0));` is mentioned 4 times inside the file. I have replaced all. still filling with black.

Answer (score 0):

The library you are using sets the background of every new image-resource to black.
For example - check the [`resize` function](https://gist.github.com/miguelxt/908143#file-simpleimage-php-L123) or the [`cut` function](https://gist.github.com/miguelxt/908143#file-simpleimage-php-L134). You can see this in both functions:

```
imagecolortransparent($new_image, imagecolorallocate($new_image, 0, 0, 0));
```

> By default - the background color of a new image is configured to be the **first** color that was allocated, and since there is a call inside these functions to `imagecolorallocate($new_image, 0, 0, 0)` - the background color is configured to be black.

Since you are saving the image as `JPEG`, and the jpeg format doesn't support transparency - your background will be black.

If you really want you can change all of the code in that library from:

```
imagecolorallocate($new_image, 0, 0, 0)
```

To:

```
imagecolorallocate($new_image, 255, 255, 255)
```

This will change the background of all the new images the library will create to white.